# minicom cmd not showing

Tags: connections, serial

I am using minicom in centos to try to connect to a cisco router. I did the configuration with  `minicom -s`  changed the serial port to the appropriate one `/dev/ttyS1`. Saved as dfl. and Exit.

When minicom started i got the following.

```
Welcome to minicom 2.3
Options: 118n
Compiled on Nov 23 2010, 13:27:13
Port /dev/ttyS1

        press CTRL-A z for help on special keys
```

I don't see the  `cmd:`  line though. Do i need to set up anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may need to initialize the modem. Hit CTRL+A z to get to the Help menu then "M".

Comment: Thank, I initialized the modem. I got '###############' and that was it. still no  cmd:

Comment: That could just be the cisco router decompressing the image. Try hitting enter a few times to see if it brings anything else up. Also make sure the settings for the serial connection are: `9600 8N1` under Help > Parameters.